# I get a parse error, when trying to specify cost benchmark for bcrypt hashing algorithm?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

Can't figure out why i get a parse/syntax error in my code, it works on my localhost server, but when i upload it to my webhost i get a syntax error:  "unexpected '[' on line 3".

I have a paste-link here: http://codepad.org/26K93MPG

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$options = [
    'cost' => 9,
];

$unhashedPassword = 'testingtesting';
$hashedPassword = password_hash($unhashedPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

echo $unhashedPassword . "<br>";
echo $hashedPassword;

?>
```

**FIXED!**
Here's how i fixed it, and a short explanation about what went wrong:

Firstly, My localhost server's PHP Version was 5.6.4, and my production server's PHP Version was 5.3.29. Since the password_hash() function was first introduced in Version 5.3.7, its obvious that it didnt work.

Secondly, the array syntax that i was using was only allowed in PHP Version 5.3 or older. But the old syntax didnt make it work either, but that was because the password_hash() function wasnt implemented in PHP at that time either.

**To fix both problems:**

1) Go to https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php

2) Put this library file into your folder, and include password.php in your login procedure.

3) change the array syntax to this, it's nice and neat:

```
<?php
include("password_hash_compatibility.php");

$unhashedPassword = 'testingtesting';
$hashedPassword = password_hash($unhashedPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 9));

echo $unhashedPassword . "<br>";
echo $hashedPassword;

?>
```

Comment: What is the server? Is that the full error log? You need to give some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your production server is running PHP 5.3 or older and thus does not offer array shorthand syntax which was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Just use the "old" array syntax for backwards compatibility:

```
$options = array(
    'cost' => 9,
);
```

This is why you should always make sure your development environment matches your production environment as closely as possible.

Comment: Exactly, just ran a phpinfo() function. My production server is running 5.3, and my localhost server is running 5.6. But when i upload the "old" array syntax to my webhosting system, it won't work. Either on my local or production server, thats pretty fustrating :S

Comment: Even if i remove the array, and live with no benchmark control, it wont work on the production server. But works on my localhost. just found out that my webhosting is running PHP Version 5.3.29 .. Which makes it pretty damn annoying because password_hash() was introduced in 5.3.7 .. Grr .. How hard can it be to have the newest version of php when they have so many customers.

Comment: You can use `password_hash()` if you use [this backwards compatible library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: It's because they have so many customers that they find it hard to upgrade PHP. If you upgrade without giving users a chance to make sure their code works with the new PHP you break websites which will cause them to lose customers.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, i've posted the solution in the question :)